# Implementing combined authorization (OAuth, OpenID etc) using PHP

Tags: php, oauth, openid, authentication

I'm writing my own authentification library with PHP. I want to implement not only old-style Login/Pass authorization, but also OAuth and OpenID services (maybe others too) as drivers. These drivers will work with different data (tokens or simple array or any else), so I need to create separated tables for drivers + one main table for basic user information (`ID`, `Screenname` etc).

So, how do implement (or use existing) Auth libraries? I'm not asking for help with coding, just want to collect ideas, howtos and other best practices.

Comment: nothing wrong with your english :)

Comment: Just want to notice that oauth is **authorization** protocol and openid is **authentication** protocol.

Comment: But both can be used for authentification ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you want to create a library that will support all of these at the same time? So User A can be logged in via OAuth and User B logged in via OpenID? And the library you are creating is to be used for providing simple "1 way calls"?

I implemented something like that (for short url drivers) in a simple framework for XenForo. I did it by creating a generic class with a function called "shorten($url, $method)" and dynamically checked to make sure that the method's driver existed in the specified directory (XenForo has Zend Framework's AutoLoading, so we utilize that) and build function calls. I then pass necessary information on (only $url) and let the driver fetch the information.

If you are storing all necessary information with the user, you could have an "extraData" database field with all necessary information for the specified "method" serialized or stored in a uniform manner that can be passed to the driver.

My co-developer and I chose to abstract it enough that we would be able to release it and any other developer could easily add & install new drivers for the framework. I can provide sample code if you'd like, but it includes several XenForo specific items. Speaking of which, I like the way it worked, and may implement it in a non-XenForo specific method.

Comment: Of course, show your code :) I will try to understand it. You can use pseudo-code if it will be simplier.

Comment: Actually, since I have quite a bit of code, I will post a link to a downloadable zip. Give me a minute or two to remove some XenForo specific parts.

Comment: Since the Shorten class is kind of long (and I can't edit my last comment), a link will be easier (not a plug). I have included the Shorten_URL class as well as one method to demonstrate the basic structure. We developed several methods and each one resides in its own file (for autoloader purposes) and includes XenForo specific stuff. However, one should demonstrate the idea). Here is that download: [link](http://kingkovifor.com//public_html/code/stack/XenForo_ShortenURL.zip)

Comment: Sorry, not sure where the /public_html/ came into play, but here is a correct one: [link](http://kingkovifor.com/code/stack/XenForo_ShortenURL.zip)